# Not able to install a gem file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hi People I am trying to install a gem file through command prompt on MAC using the following command "gem install filename" but whenever I try to execute the command I get the following error

WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/hemmanshu/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing frank-cucumber-0.8.14:
    cucumber requires gherkin (~> 2.10.0, runtime)

every time I try to execute this command the same thing pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install gems with superuser privileges so you should to use

```
sudo gem install [gemname]
```

instead of

```
gem install [gemname]
```

Comment: but do I need ruby to install the gem

Comment: Of-course, You should need the ruby to install the gem(s). Here is the tutorial site for installing the ruby on MAC. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/

Comment: I am installing the gem file and when it fails it also throws an error which is as follows -:  cucumber requires gherkin how do I remedy this error

Comment: I think, the particular gem "gherkin" is not installed or not properly configured (version mismatch). So, You need to reinstall the "gherkin" using the following command. sudo gem uninstall gherkin
sudo gem install gherkin   (or)  sudo gem install gherkin --version 2.10.0. then try to install cucumber.

Comment: Cucumber is not installed the gem "gherkin" automatically. So you need to install the gem before installing the cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

U try with sudo.  like "sudo gem install filename"

Answer (score 0):

...Most of the time this is a PATH issue, Suppose you are using zshell as me, then add this line at the end of `~/.zshrc` file 
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin"`
If you are using bash as default shell then add this line to end of `~/.bashrc` file 
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin"`

For your case it will be like this: 
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin`

Lastly don't forget to reload the shell by `source ~/.zshrc` incase of z-shell or `source ~/.bashrc` incase of bash-shell. I think this helps someone.